# How can I take screenprint with highlighted object using UFT?

Tags: hp-uft

```
ScreenShotName = "Name_of_the_Screen2" &  CurrentTime & ".png"
ScreenName ="C:\"&ScreenShotName
Browser("Pat").Page("Car").WebEdit("UserName").Set "sdfsdf"
Browser("Pat").Page("Car").WebEdit("UserName").highlight    
Browser("Pat").Page("Car").CaptureBitmap ScreenName,True
```

I like to see image of the page with highlighting the object. It does highlight during run time but screensprint does not show highlighted object. How can I take screenprint with highlighted object?

Answer (score 0):

The `Higlight` method is synchronous, this means it does everything before the next step of the test is run.

If you want to capture the object highlighted you'll need to change the element, capture the screenshot and then restore the element. Something like this (untested):

```
' Definition
Public Function CaptureHighlight(ByRef containerObj, ByRef testObj, ByVal path)
       oldBorder = testObj.Object.style.border
       testObj.Object.style.border = "solid"
       containerObj.CaptureBitmap path, true
       testObj.Object.style.border = oldBorder
End Function


' Usage
CaptureHighlight Browser("Pat").Page("Car"), Browser("Pat").Page("Car").WebEdit("UserName"), ScreenName
```